# Button as image not showing up in the centre

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

I have a calculator with several buttons, however, when I try to add an image for the "reset" button it shows up in a way that pushes the entire final row down slightly and then it looks uneven:
[image: calculator showing text 'select two numbers' and a red button out of place]

I just want the reset button to be levelled with the rest - without any addition to the top or bottom area of the button.

I have tried several things online but nothing has worked, most of what I tried just adding more white space to the top and bottom (therefore making it more out of place) or just doing nothing at all.

HTML:

```
<button class = "jsnumberButton allButtons" id = "1">
1 
</button>

<button class = "jsnumberButton allButtons" id = "2">
2
</button>

<button class = "jsnumberButton allButtons" id = "3">
3
</button>
<p></p>

<button class = "jsnumberButton allButtons" id = "4">
4
</button>

<button class = "jsnumberButton allButtons" id = "5">
5
</button>

<button class = "jsnumberButton allButtons" id = "6">
6
</button>

<p></p>

<button class = "jsnumberButton allButtons" id = "7">
7
</button>

<button class = "jsnumberButton allButtons" id = "8">
8
</button>

<button class = "jsnumberButton allButtons" id = "9">
9
</button>
<p></p>

<button class = "jsnumberButton allButtons" id = "0">
0
</button>

<button class = "jsoperatorButton" id = "plus">
+
</button>

<button class = "jsoperatorButton" id = "minus">
-
</button>
<p></p>

<button class = "jsoperatorButton" id = "multiply">
x
</button>

<button class = "jsoperatorButton" id = "divide">
/
</button>

<button class = "jsoperatorButtonEqual" id = "equal">
=
</button>
<p></p>
<button class = "js-resetButton" id = "reset">
Reset
</button>

<p class = "js-displayTotalOne"></p>
<p class = "js-displayOperator"></p>
<p class = "js-displayTotalTwo"></p>
<p class="js-calculationDisplay"></p>
```

CSS:

```
<style>
    .allButtons {
        background-color:#6557b4;
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        border: none;
        color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 16px;
    
            border-radius: 16px;

            font-family: cursive
           
        }

        .jsoperatorButton{
            background-color: #6ec581;
            width: 40px;
            height: 40px;
            border: none;
            color:#ffffff;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size: 20px;
            border-radius: 16px;
            font-family: cursive;

        }
        .jsoperatorButtonEqual{
            background-color:#cf8674;
            width: 40px;
            height: 40px;
            border: none;
            font-size: 20px;
            color:#ffffff;
            text-align: center;
            border-radius: 16px;
            font-family: cursive;
            font-weight: bold;

        }
      
    .js-resetButton{

        background-color:#c43737;
        color: #ffffff;
        border-radius: 18px;
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        font-size: 10px

    }

    </style>
```

Comment: add full code html

Comment: Try `vertical-align: middle`.

Answer (score 0):

You should the calculator buttons in a grid such as this cause it makes it easier
to align properly. In this example you should do this:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>My Website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <link rel="icon" href="./favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
</head>

<body>
    <button class="jsnumberButton allButtons" id="1">
        1
    </button>

    <button class="jsnumberButton allButtons" id="2">
        2
    </button>

    <button class="jsnumberButton allButtons" id="3">
        3
    </button>
    <p></p>

    <button class="jsnumberButton allButtons" id="4">
        4
    </button>

    <button class="jsnumberButton allButtons" id="5">
        5
    </button>

    <button class="jsnumberButton allButtons" id="6">
        6
    </button>

    <p></p>

    <button class="jsnumberButton allButtons" id="7">
        7
    </button>

    <button class="jsnumberButton allButtons" id="8">
        8
    </button>

    <button class="jsnumberButton allButtons" id="9">
        9
    </button>
    <p></p>

    <button class="jsnumberButton allButtons" id="0">
        0
    </button>

    <button class="jsoperatorButton" id="plus">
        +
    </button>

    <button class="jsoperatorButton" id="minus">
        -
    </button>
    <p></p>
    <div class="allOperators">
        <button class="jsoperatorButton" id="multiply">
            x
        </button>

        <button class="jsoperatorButton" id="divide">
            /
        </button>

        <button class="jsoperatorButtonEqual" id="equal">
            =
        </button>
        <p></p>
        <button class="js-resetButton" id="reset">
            Reset
        </button>
    </div>
    <p class="js-displayTotalOne"></p>
    <p class="js-displayOperator"></p>
    <p class="js-displayTotalTwo"></p>
    <p class="js-calculationDisplay"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
.allButtons {
  background-color: #6557b4;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: none;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;

  border-radius: 16px;

  font-family: cursive;
}

.jsoperatorButton {
  background-color: #6ec581;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  font-family: cursive;
}
.jsoperatorButtonEqual {
  background-color: #cf8674;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 16px;
  font-family: cursive;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.js-resetButton {
  background-color: #c43737;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 18px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 10px;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 5;
}

.allOperators {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 40px;
  grid-template-columns: 40px 40px 40px 40px;
  gap: 4px;
}
```

I created a extra div to contain all your operator buttons and aligned the content using the display: grid; function